# I don't know how to access Rate Inquiry tab of RCLGROUP site using Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

This is the analyzed page https://eservice.rclgroup.com/

I want to use Puppeteer to access the RATE INQUIRY tab but it seems to be rendered by a callGetrate() function;
I tried to use
`await page.click(querySelectorAll('a[onclick^="callGetrate"]'))` and try another way to access that **callGetrate** function by **page.evalute()**. Everything is not working. It just stops at the Booking Tab.

[Screen of the RCLGROUP page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6C9PI.png)

**This is the function of the website**

[The callgetRate function of the RCLGROUP site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2a6b.png)

**This is my code**

```
try{
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: [
      "--disable-gpu",
      "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
      "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
      "--no-sandbox",
    ],
    defaultViewport: null,
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto(`${constants.BASE_URL}e-commerce/`);



  await page.waitForSelector('#userId');
  await page.type('#userId', constants.userAccount.username , { delay: 100 });
  await page.type('#password', constants.userAccount.password , { delay: 100 });

  await page.click('input[type=submit]');

  await page.evaluate(() => {
    callGetrate();
  })


    
  const cookie = await page.cookies();
  console.log(cookie);


  return cookie.map((x) => `${x.name}=${x.value}`).join("; ");  

  }catch(error){
    console.log("Failed to Login RCL ", error);
  }
}
```

**Please help me!**

Comment: Link says: "Unable to redirect."

Comment: @GrafiCode actually the full path of the page is https://eservice.rclgroup.com/e-commerce/ 
I have concatenated it with the e-commerce/ string in the above code